# Is there a way to list the private or unlisted videos for a channel?

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I want to list all of the private videos for the logged in user. To start with, I'm using [this code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#my_uploaded_videos) from the API to list all videos from a user's channel. The only way that I've found to get this to work is to do 3 operations, first get the playlist for the channel, then get the videos for the channel uploaded playlist, then add those videos to an ID list and finally pass that in to the videos.list. Very simplified version:

- gapi.client.youtube.channels.list {mine:true, part:'contentDetails'}
- gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list {playlistId: playlistId, part: 'status,snippet'}, where the playlistId was found from the previous operation
- gapi.client.youtube.videos.list : Ids found from the previous list that are private (Or unlisted)

The key code that I'm currently using for the middle operation is:

```
function requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId,pageToken) {
  $('#video-container').html('');
  var requestOptions = {
    playlistId: playlistId,
    part: 'status,snippet',
    maxResults: 50
  };

  var found=false

  if (pageToken) {
    requestOptions.pageToken = pageToken;
  }
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);
  request.execute(function(response) {
    // Only show pagination buttons if there is a pagination token for the
    // next or previous page of results.
    pageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;

    var playlistItems = response.result.items;
    if (playlistItems) {
      $.each(playlistItems, function(index, item) {
        if (item.status.privacyStatus=='private') {
            ids.push(item.snippet.resourceId.videoId)
            //found=true
        }
      });
      if (found) {
          //Do stuff
      } else {
          //Do other stuff
      }
    }
  });
}
```

It seems like there should be a way to filter based on the privacyStatus, as there is when you are in the YouTube Creator Studio, but if there is, I sure can't find one. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: According to [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list](PlaylistItems: list) there isn't any way to filter based on privacy setting.